# DPDK Running As Non Privileged User

Tags: linux, permissions, system-administration, dpdk

I have an issue running DPDK helloworld application as non privileged user.

```
[@dredd examples]$ ./dpdk-helloworld
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: rte_mem_virt2phy(): cannot open /proc/self/pagemap: Permission denied
EAL: FATAL: Cannot use IOVA as 'PA' since physical addresses are not available
EAL: Cannot use IOVA as 'PA' since physical addresses are not available
PANIC in main():
Cannot init EAL
5: [./dpdk-helloworld(_start+0x2e) [0x58ce4e]]
4: [/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f93977edcf3]]
3: [./dpdk-helloworld(main+0x42) [0x58cf87]]
2: [./dpdk-helloworld(__rte_panic+0xdb) [0xa01c59]]
1: [./dpdk-helloworld(rte_dump_stack+0x27) [0xa2fcac]]
```

Clearly this issue is described in [DPDK guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/enable_func.html#running-without-root-privileges) and it advises adding the capability to the executable which I did but it didn't work.

```
[XXX@dredd examples]$ sudo setcap cap_ipc_lock,cap_sys_admin+ep ./dpdk-helloworld
[sudo] password for XXX:
[XXX@dredd examples]$ getcap ./dpdk-helloworld
./dpdk-helloworld = cap_ipc_lock,cap_sys_admin+ep
[XXX@dredd examples]$
```

On other hand I have seen [some pages](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt) that claim that running user itself must have the SYS_ADMIN capability. So does it mean that DPDK guide is not updated, and what why file permission may not be sufficient???

Any advises on how to overcome the permission issue for the DPDK application will be highly appreciated.

Running with sudo it seams to be working:-

```
[@dredd examples]$ sudo ./dpdk-helloworld 
[sudo] password for XXX:
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(2)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_em (8086:100e) device: 0000:00:08.0 (socket 0)
```

The environment is VirtualBox AlmaLinux

```
[XXX@dredd examples]$ uname -a
Linux dredd 4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 9 06:28:28 EST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have bound two pci devices to vfio-pci driver with disabled ***iommu*** support

Answer (score 0):

sudo setcap all+ep ./dpdk-helloworld

But it is far from intended granularity of the solution